# How to count missing data using two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['11','11','11','11','22','22','43','43'], 'x': ['d1', 'd2','d3','d4','d1','d2','d1','d3'], 'b': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['d1', 'd2','d3','d4']})
```

`df1` is the original dataframe where I need to add data

`df2` is my dataframe to compare columns

`df1`:

```
    a   x  b
0  11  d1  1
1  11  d2  2
2  11  d3  3
3  11  d4  4
4  22  d1  5
5  22  d2  6
6  43  d1  7
7  43  d3  8
```

`df2`:

```
    x
0  d1
1  d2
2  d3
3  d4
```

How to count how many rows from column `X` (`df1`) are missing regarding column `A` (`df1`) when I compare to data from `df2`? For example:

`df1` is missing `d3` and `d4` for `22`

`df1` is also missing `d2` and `d4` for `43`

Is it possible to add those rows to `df1`?

Comment: `df2` is redundant in your example, it just tells us `df1['x'].unique()`, you'd get the same effect just by iterating over `df1.groupby('x') ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby` and then `.apply` an right merge, how to handle the indices might be tricky, but just dropping them might work for you:

```
>>> df1.groupby('a', as_index=False).apply(lambda d: d.merge(df2, on='x', how='right')).reset_index(drop=True)
      a   x    b
0    11  d1  1.0
1    11  d2  2.0
2    11  d3  3.0
3    11  d4  4.0
4    22  d1  5.0
5    22  d2  6.0
6   NaN  d3  NaN
7   NaN  d4  NaN
8    43  d1  7.0
9    43  d3  8.0
10  NaN  d2  NaN
11  NaN  d4  NaN
```

You can deal with those missing values with `fillna`, so something like:

```
>>> result = (
...     df1.groupby('a', as_index=False)
...        .apply(lambda d: d.merge(df2, on='x', how='right'))
...        .reset_index(drop=True)
... )
>>> result['a'] = result['a'].fillna(method='ffill')
>>> result
     a   x    b
0   11  d1  1.0
1   11  d2  2.0
2   11  d3  3.0
3   11  d4  4.0
4   22  d1  5.0
5   22  d2  6.0
6   22  d3  NaN
7   22  d4  NaN
8   43  d1  7.0
9   43  d2  NaN
10  43  d3  8.0
11  43  d4  NaN
```

Comment: I've tried this but on the goupby I have this problem: 

rows 10 and 11 (NaN d2/d4 NaN) go up to rows 8 and 9. So when I apply "fillna", I have "NaN d2/d4 NaN" assigned to "22" when I need then assigned to "43"

Answer (score 2):

You can try a `for` loop:

```
x_set = set(df2['x'])

{k:x_set.difference(set(d)) for k,d in df1.groupby('a')['x']}
```

Output:

```
{'11': set(), '22': {'d3', 'd4'}, '43': {'d2', 'd4'}}
```

If you want the length:

```
lengths = {k:len(x_set.difference(set(d))) k,d in df1.groupby('a')['x']}
```

And to map it back:

```
df1['len'] = df['a'].map(lengths)
```